# Troubles with nested forms in Rails ( input field not displaying; creating returns undefined method error )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have problem creating nested form.

One problem is that **text input field for the child element (project description) is not displaying**.

**Second problem is that once I create a new Project, index action returns a 'undefined method for nil object '**. I think that is because of the total absence of ProjectDecription (it cannot return project.project_description.description if the project_description doesn't exist).

**Also, ProjectDescription is succesfully saved in database**(without project description)Please help.

These are my models in question:

a) The Project model

```
  1  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  2   has_one :project_description
  3   accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_description
  4  end
```

b)The ProjectDescription model

```
  1 class ProjectDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  2   belongs_to :project
  3 end
```

This is my projects_controller.rb

```
  1 class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  2     
  3   def index
  4     @projects = Project.all
  5   end 
  6     
  7   def new
  8     @project = Project.new
  9     @project.project_description = ProjectDescription.new
 10   end 
 11     
 12   def create
 13     @project = Project.new(params[:project])
 14       
 15     if @project.save
 16       redirect_to (projects_path)
 17     else
 18       new_project_path
 19     end
 20   end 
 21 
 22   def show
 23     @project = Project.find(params[:id])
 24   end
 25
 26  end
```

This is my projects/index.html.erb view (I think line 5 causes the undefined method error)

```
  1 <%= link_to 'Create new project', new_project_path %>
  2   <h1>Projects</h1>
  3   <% @projects.each do |p| %>
  4     <h2><%= link_to p.project_name, project_path(p) %></h2>
  5     <%= p.project_description.description %>
  6     <br/>
  7     <% p.users.each do |u| %>
  8       <%= u.user_name %>
  9       <br/>
 10     <% end %>
 11     <br/>
 12   <% end %>
```

This is my projects/new.html.erb view (text field specified in line 9 doesn't show)

```
  1 <h2>Create new Project</h2>
  2 <%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  3   Project name:
  4   <%= f.text_field :project_name %><br/>
  5 
  6   Project descripiton:
  7   <% @project.build_project_description unless @project.project_description %>
  8   <% f.fields_for :project_description do |builder| %>
  9     <%= builder.text_field :description %>
 10   <% end %>
 11   <br/>
 12   <%= submit_tag ("Create Project") %>
 13 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `<%= p.project_description.description %>` throws an error because there is at least one project without description, so `p.project_description` returns `nil`, and the next call `nil.description` throws a NoMethodError (`nil` has not a `description` method). An elegant way to resolve these situations is the `try` method (you can read about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)):

```
<%= p.project_description.try(:description) %>
```

This line will return `nil` if `project_description` is `nil`, otherwise it will return the  value of `description` field.

Regarding the second problem I think the code you posted should work; anyway, try this:

```
<% f.fields_for @project.project_description do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_field :description %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. 1st problem solved. 2nd problem remains though. Still no text field displaying. Have any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you :) Sorry for the delay, I didn't see the comment >.< Anyway, I think I found the error: there is a missing `=` at the beginning of the fields_for:
`<%= f.fields_for :project_description do |builder| %>`